# Faster way to create Drivers?

Tags: drivers

I've been using a lot of drivers. I'm pretty comfortable with them actually, but I wanted to know if there was a faster way to set them up than > right click > add driver > decide variable type > rotation > quaternion > type equation.

Like, if I know that I want to use the 'x' rotation from a hand bone as an input variable. Is there no way to just go to the x rotation variable in the properties menu, copy it > and when I add driver, it automatically be used as my input variable??

Thank you for your time!

Comment: This might not be enough, but you can right-click on any property field and select 'Copy as New Driver' .. You can then right-click on a target field and 'Paste Driver'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you right-click a property, one of the options is "Copy as New Driver" and another is "Paste Driver."
[image]

[image]

This will create a new driver in the target with "Type" set to "Average Value." Change the type to "Scripted Expression" to get standard expression dialog.

Comment: Cool, that's very close to what I was hoping for, but when I do that, and go in to edit the driver, there is nowhere for me to type an expression. How do I get the expression area to show up after doing it this way?

Comment: Change the driver type to "Scripted Expression" to get standard expression dialog.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly what I wanted to know :)